# Erasing JTable BOTTOM white border

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

After erasing borders and headers, my JTable looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, a white border is seen at the bottom of the table, and I see no reason at my code for this to happen. How can I erase that?

The code for the JTable is:

```
Object[][] datosMeasurements = {};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(datosMeasurements, nombresColumnasTablas);
    tablaMeasurements = new JTable(model){
      public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            if(colIndex==1){
                return true;
            }
            return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
      }
    };
    model.addTableModelListener(new CambioTablaMeasurementListener());
    TableCellRenderer rendererMeasurements = new paramRenderer();
    tablaMeasurements.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, rendererMeasurements);
    ((DefaultCellEditor) tablaMeasurements.getDefaultEditor(Object.class)).setClickCountToStart(1);

    JScrollPane scrollMeasurements = new JScrollPane(tablaMeasurements);
    tablaMeasurements.setTableHeader(null);
    scrollMeasurements.setColumnHeaderView(null);
    tablaMeasurements.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

And for its renderer:

```
class paramRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private final DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#.000" );
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table,
                    Object value,
                    boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus,
                    int row,
                    int column)
    {
        //value = formatter.format((Number)value);
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        setEnabled(table == null || table.isEnabled());

        if (column == 0)
            setHorizontalAlignment( RIGHT );
        else if (column == 1)
            setHorizontalAlignment( CENTER );
        else
            setHorizontalAlignment( LEFT );    

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
              TableColumn columna = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
              if (i==0) columna.setPreferredWidth(65);
              if (i==1) columna.setPreferredWidth(75);
              if (i==2) columna.setPreferredWidth(30);
            }

        if(isSelected)
        {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            if (row==0 || row==2) setBackground(new java.awt.Color(211, 217, 255));
            else setBackground(java.awt.Color.white); 
        }
        else
        {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            if (row==0 || row==2) setBackground(new java.awt.Color(211, 217, 255));
            else setBackground(java.awt.Color.white); 
        }

        return this;
    }
    public void setValue() {    
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you see that? I only see the PreferredWidth, but that has nothing to do with the problem...

Comment: still not learned to stick to java naming conventions?

Comment: bad habits seem to spread exponentially, so repeating myself (even though unrelated to the problem here): Do.Not.Change.Caller's. State.In.Renderer's.getXXComponent. Never-ever ... and that means: really-really-never. Here: Column sizing must be done somewhere else.

Comment: Does that apply for the row's colors too? Thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: there is no such thing as "row color" - it's the color property of the rendering component that's set. And sure, it's perfectly valid to set it, after all that's the job of a renderer :-) What's not allowed is to set any property of the table from within the renderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculate the prefScrollableViewportSize in terms of rowHeight, something like

```
int visibleRowCount = 10;
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
     new Dimension(myWidth, visibleRowCount * table.getRowHeight()));
```

Comment: @mKorbel what has the header to do with the view viewport size? Nothing, obviously ;-)

Comment: table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize does not accept (int, int) parameters. I tried to use as a parameter a Dimension(int, int) with the parameters you described, but nothing happens

Comment: @Roman you're right, the method takes a Dimension. Setting that works for me: the table inside the scrollPane is exactly sized to fit the given number of rows

Comment: I tried with tablaPretratamiento.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100, 5 * tablaPretratamiento.getRowHeight())); and nothing. I even tried to set Dimension(50,50) to see if the table gets truncated, but there is no change at all either. Maybe I'm writting some code after that which is making this method fail?

Comment: @Roman don't know what you are doing wrong, my crystal ball is cloudy ;-) In other words: edit your question and show a small (max 50 lines!) standalone (no custom classes) runnable example that demonstrates the problem. Good chance that you'll find the problem yourself in the process :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is probable the tables "viewPort". You can try with:

```
yourTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Comment: I tried to put it after: tablaMeasurements.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100,100)); but nothing happens. If i comment this line, nothing happens either